# Retrieve group subscribers

Tags: api, marketing-cloud, ruby

Using the exacttarget API, how can one retrieve the subscribers for a group?

There is a 'Subscribers' attribute on the 'Group' object, however when I include 'Subscribers' in the retrieve request I get an undefined attribute error.

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/group/

Here is most of it ... in Ruby

`props = {
  :object => 'Group',
  :props => [ "ID", "Name", "CreatedDate", "Subscriber"]
}`


`filter = {
  :filterType => 'Simple',
  :filter => ['Name','equals', "Not Healy Crowd" ]
}`


`lists = BuildRetrieve.new
resp = filtered_query(props, filter)`


`puts resp.inspect
resp.results.each do |result|
  #puts result.inspect
  puts "#{result.iD },#{result.name}, #{result.createdDate} "
end`

Comment: Would you be willing to post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question ...

Exact target treats groups like lists.  Therefore I used the solution provided in this example ...

http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_all_subscribers_on_a_list/

.. and replaced the value for the "ListID" property with the selected group id.